# Is there a way to output code chunk with stan formatting, reading file from R?

Tags: r, quarto, stan

I've got a Stan model that I'd like to include in a Quarto doc (without copying/pasting code over). Currently, I can do this with:

````
```{r}
writeLines(readLines("model.stan"))
````

This gives the stan code, but formatted as a character string output from R --- is there a way to apply Stan's syntax highlighting to the output? [This](https://fediscience.org/@andrew/110313483902096396) gives an example of outputting bash formatting, but I've been unable thus far to recreate with stan.

Comment: Where are “writing” those lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the chunk option `#| class-output: stan` and use `cat(readLines("<filename.ext>"), sep = "\n")`.

````
---
title: Test
format: html
---

```{r}
#| class-output: stan
#| echo: false
cat(readLines("test.stan"), sep = "\n")
```
````

However, in Quarto there is a more easy way to do that using the quarto extension [`include-code-files`](https://github.com/quarto-ext/include-code-files).

````
---
title: Test
format: html
filters:
   - include-code-files
---

```{.stan include="test.stan"}
```
````

---

**output**

[image: stan code with syntax highlighting]

---

**test.stan**

```
data {
  int<lower=0> N;
  vector[N] x;
  vector[N] y;
}
parameters {
  real alpha;
  real beta;
  real<lower=0> sigma;
}
model {
  y ~ normal(alpha + beta * x, sigma);
}
```

Comment: thanks --- this is great! I ended up also installing your extension that supports code folding

Comment: @MarkRieke, I am glad that you found the extensions helpful. Let me know if there's any way I can improve that extension!

Comment: Adding a [link](https://github.com/shafayetShafee/add-code-files) to the `add-code-files` extension for others in the future who want to include code from other files in foldable chunks as well